# How to add manual approver to Jenkins job

Tags: jenkins

I have a job that updates the databases for TEST servers and this job should be run by support after an approval from Account Manager
The job is parameterized and I need a way to pause build until the approver approves running the build

EX. When the support click on Build , an Email should be sent to the approver and whenever the approver responds to the link the job will start running.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you add the code to your question? In general you should check the [ask] page.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking a bit much here.  Jenkins is a build tool rather than a change management tracker.
You can setup a manual approvals step e.g.

```
steps {
    timeout(time: 1, unit: 'HOURS') {
        input(message: "restart thes instance?", submitter: 'admin-team')
    }
}
```

Where admin-team is an AD group referenced in an authorization strategy.
You also wouldnt get an email (you could set this up with more code), and the approver would have to login to Jenkins to check the button.

To do something like you are asking you would probably want to have Jira or something handle you approvals (e.g. move a ticket to approved), and that fires a webhook to start the Jenkins job.